# Regex - match if the number of occurences of x is the same as y

Tags: python, regex

I try to make a regex matches if the times that x appears in a string is equal to the time y appears

For example: "..X..Y..Y.X.." should match
For example: "..X..Y..Y.X..X" should not match

It's a part of a more complex regex, so I can't do it using simply the count function of Python.

Thanks for the help

Comment: *a part of a more complex regex* - show that regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "..X..Y..Y.X.." 
if len(re.findall("X", s)) == len(re.findall("Y", s)):
    pass
```